# Nodejs: Return a json object that maintains their primitive types

Tags: node.js, json

I am writing an endpoint and would like to return a json with various objects that retain its original type, ie `Int` or `Date`. However my implementation simply converted them to `string`.

```
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let query = req.query
    return getContents()
    .then((contents) => {
        let jsonObject = {
            articles: contents
        }
        return res.json(jsonObject)
    })
}
```

The `contents` above is an array of objects like so:

```
{
    date_created: 2020-05-15T00:00:00.000Z,
    read_count: 10
    //Other attributes with string values
}
```

After receiving the `json` object in front-end, the `date_created` and `read_count` has morphed into strings like so:

```
{
    date_created: "2020-05-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    read_count: "10"
    //Other attributes with string values
}
```

I have attempted the following but still strips the types off:

```
let jsonObject = {
    articles: JSON.stringify(contents)
}

let jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
    articles: contents
})
```

How can I retain the `Date` and `Int` object types in the returned json?

Comment: Can you not cast it to the type you need on the front end? Once you receive the JSON object and extract whatever item, just cast it to the type you need? BUT JSON object does retain the type of item inserted so it is possible to have an INT, INT, STRING json object. 

Note for the ISO date in 'contents' if you are using toISOString() then this will convert the date object to STRING.

Comment: That's not really ideal for mobile dev teams as the data model has already been in place

Comment: Try using JSON.parse() instead of JSON.stringify().

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I am not using `toISOString()` for the date. I have also visually inspect and confirm that the date in `jsonObject` are actual `date` objects before the `res.json()`.

Comment: Also in your return statement try use 'return JSON.parse(jsonObject)'.  You have to parse the data somewhere - hard to see exactly where but I think JSON.parse() will solve your issue.

Comment: JSON has limited types and there is no support for Dates. On the other hand, numbers *are* supported and you might be doing something strange to make them string in the JSON - a value can be one of: object array string number "true" "false" "null"

Comment: @crashmstr I doubt so. I have used API's that returns `date` objects in their json, allowing mobile dev teams to directly decode the json object into custom data models.

Comment: @Koh many systems can convert JSON values into dates easily (for example, Newtonsoft's JSON.Net and deserializing to a class), but there should be no doubt that JSON does not support dates *directly* in the formatted string. object array string number "true" "false" "null" are the only data types.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may solve your issue -

```
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let query = req.query
    return getContents()
    .then((contents) => {
        let jsonObject = {
            articles: contents
        }
        return JSON.parse(jsonObject)
    })
}
```

You store the data as JSON but you also need to parse it. When receiving data from a server, the data is always a string.

Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should know is that `res.json()` uses `JSON.stringify()` under the hood to convert the JavaScript object to JSON.

And JSON doesn't support many types of values that a javascript object may have, so it converts them to something it knows like `Date()` will be parsed to a String and a `function(){}` will be parsed to `"{}"`.

So, what I think is to replace `res.json(jsonObject)` to `res.send(jsonObject)`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I just tried `res.send(jsonObject)` but it still returns string dates